# Redirecting feign & ribbon logs to log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-feign

I currently use spring cloud netflix with log4j2. The log4j2 configuration comes from the xml in the classpath. When I run the app, I see that the feign & ribbon logs are not being redirected to the logger specified in the configuration. I have configured log for **com.netflix.ribbon** & **feign** packages to be logged at **debug** level.

However, log configured for spring is properly redirecting to the specified appender, ribbon & feign are not.

I am using gradle with spring-boot-starter-logging ignored & added spring-boot-starter-log4j2 in as part of my build.

I see that feign [has a way](https://github.com/Netflix/feign/tree/master/slf4j) by which we can configure slf4j, but since we use annotation driven feign support, I cant configure the feign to use slf4j for logging.

Any help is appreciated.

My log4j2.xml looks some what like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
        <Property name="log-fileName">test</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="trace-log" fileName="${log-path}/${log-fileName}-trace.log" filePattern="${log-path}/${log-fileName}_trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/${log-fileName}-error.log" filePattern="${log-path}/${log-fileName}_error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="trace-log" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="feign" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="trace-log" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="com.netflix.ribbon" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="trace-log" />
        </logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log"></AppenderRef>
            <AppenderRef ref="error-log" level="ERROR"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

PS: The reason for debugging feign/ribbon is to understand a weird feign behavior between two different machines in our micro services setup

Comment: You can create a bean of type `feign.Logger` that gets autowired in.  A `feign.slf4j.Slf4jLogger` is the default. One of the issues is there is only one logger (ie the log name) `feign.Logger`.

Comment: Added the following bean to the boot application class & it dint help.

 @Bean
 public Logger feignLogger() {
  return new Slf4jLogger();
 }

Do I need to make any log4j2.xml changes (other than the logger thats already registered with logger name set to *feign*)?

Comment: FYI, I annotate the stub interface with @FeignClient & I am using Spring boot 1.2.1.RELEASE& spring cloud version of 1.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: I have never worked with log4j2, so I cannot help there.

Comment: Spencer, Thanks. @dsyer, any suggestion on this?

Comment: @spencergibb I'm not able to make it work with default logging aswell. The sample project can be found @ https://github.com/thekalinga/sample-cloud-app-no-discovery-war

With default logging, I'm able to see logs from com.netflix, but not from feign

Answer (score 5):

Looking at Spring Cloud's `FeignClientFactoryBean` shows that you can optionally autowire a bean of type `feign.Logger.Level`. Try registering such a bean in your `@Configuration`using

```
@Bean
public feign.Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
    return feign.Logger.Level.FULL;
}
```

Comment: I have tried with this option. I only see logs from com.netflix, not form feign. I used logback for this test (not log4j2)

Comment: Also put `logging.level.feign=DEBUG` into your `application.properties`.

Comment: Yes.. I have set logging.level for both com.netflix & feign to DEBUG when I tried before

Answer (score 0):

@jensfischerhh's answer would fix many cases but looks mistakenly missed one thig.

You need to **config feign generated class's logger level** with feignLoggerLevel Bean.

Both config must be exist together.

[related doccument in spring-cloud-netflix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/431)

bean config ( in @Configuration annotated class )

```
@Bean
public feign.Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
    return feign.Logger.Level.FULL;
}
```

log config

```
</Configuration>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="your.feign-interface-package" level="trace">
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```